# connection error on running NGINX with uWSGI server

Tags: python, unix, nginx, uwsgi

Nginx is running in machine 1 with the following configuration:

```
daemon off;

worker_processes 1 ;

events
{
     worker_connections 1024;
}

http {


log_format upstream_time '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                         '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                         '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"'
                         'rt=$request_time urt="$upstream_response_time"';

access_log /u/user1/logs/access.log upstream_time;

server {

   listen 7876;

   server_name NGINSERVER;

   location /d {
        include         /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      <UWSGIRUNNINGMACHINENAME>:7877;
        uwsgi_read_timeout  30s;
    }
}
```

uWSGI is running in machine 2 with the following configuration:

```
[d]
master = true
workers = 5
socket = 127.0.0.1:7877
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
close-on-exec = true
chdir = /u/user1/prpject/src
module = test.run
```

If i start the NGINX and uWSGI in the same machine, then the connection is established successfully.

The problem starts when i try to run them in different machines,

> 2016/03/28 05:13:44 [error] 370#0: *16 connect() to unix:/u/user1/socks/data.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xx.xxx.xx, server: NGINserver, request: "GET /data/20160305 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/u/user1/socks/data.sock:", host: "domain.com:7876"

Please help!

Comment: UNIX domain socket can only connect on the same host operating system. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket

Comment: @sigmalha is it recommended to have uWSGI server and NGINX server in different machine's ?

Comment: you can use the ip port , like socket = 192.168.0.2:3031. check this for detail http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html

Comment: socket must be set to 0.0.0.0:3031 right ? because uWSGI should accept all the request that it gets at port 3031. The machine IP of the machine in which uWSGI is running need not be hard coded. correct me if i am wrong @sigmalha

Comment: @sigmalha i have updated the configuration (refer the question), even after the update connection error is not resolved.

Comment: Do you the set nginx configure parameter "uwsgi_pass" right? the error message "not resolved"  seems to you do not  set the dns server well. you can try set uwsgi_pass with ip:port and check it if work, and pls update the error message.